# Python geoip find country using json

Tags: python, location, geoip

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from contextlib import closing
import json
import time
import os

while True:
    url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'
    try:
        with closing(urlopen(url)) as response:
            location = json.loads(response.read())
            location_city = location['city']
            location_state = location['region_name']
            location_country = location['country_name']
            #print(location_country)
            if location_country == "Germany":
                print("You are now surfing from: " + location_country)
                os.system(r'firefox /home/user/Documents/alert.html')
                    except:
        print("Could not find location, searching again...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Its doesn't reply any country can I get help to solve the problem?

Comment: Your except is indented wrong. It should be indentet with 4 spaces only

Answer (score 0):

Besides of the wrong indentation, your code looks fine.

The problem seems to be that the page itself does not respond. If you try to open it in a browser for example, the connection gets refused.

Probably the api is either overloaded, or does no longer exist.

Comment: tnx , do you know any other similar service?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the server appears to be [down](http://downorisitjustme.com/res.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffreegeoip.net%2Fjson%2F).

You would probably have noticed this but the bare `except` hides the fact. In general you should not catch *all* exceptions, but should catch those that you expect - in this case a `urllib2.URLError` exception would seem appropriate:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    ...
except urllib2.URLError as exc:
    print('Could not find location due to exception: {}'.format(exc))
```

If you run the code above you might see this output:

```
Could not find location due to exception: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

The server might have been up earlier, and the problem might actually have a different cause, e.g. `json.loads()` might be failing. If you change the exception handler as shown above you will be able to see where it's failing.